# How do I fix this issue (webcam not working)

Tags: google-chrome, flash, webcam

I have a problem with my webcam working in browser, I tried Firefox and chromium first. When I go to the flash plugin setting

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html

It doesn't show the websites that I want to allow to access the webcam. So I used chrome.

In chrome I was able to allow flash to access my webcam but still doesn't work.

PS The cam works on cheese booth without an problem, and am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: is you webcam working wiht other application

Answer (score 0):

Flash is now phased out of chrome.  To fix a USB camera permissions problem (the camera wasn't working in Chrome), I ended up doing this:

`sudo chmod g+rw /dev/video0`

More detail here:

https://dmaiorino.com/?p=12

Answer (score -2):

It's probably a permissions problem.  Try adding your account to the video and audio groups under manage groups.

Also, check if you are running Chrome as an un-privileged account (rather than your own account). If you are, you'll need to add that user to video and audio groups, also.